# Почему результат не равен произведению ширины на длину пикселей?

Tags: python

```
filename = input("File for packing: ")

img = Image.open(filename)
(width, height) = img.size

Data = imageio.imread(filename)
print(Data.size)
```

Картинка размером 290 на 290 пикселей, но почему-то при запросе количества пикселей выдаёт, что всего пикселей 252300. Почему так? Ниже картинка, с которой проводил все эти махинации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [По три байта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TrueColor) на пиксель?

Comment: Точно! Спасибо, оказывается просто функция выдаёт не то, что нужно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

290 * 290 * 3, так как `size` выдаёт не количество элементов, а занимаемую память. Умножаем на 3 байта, так как каждый пиксель столько весит.